# Stripping ' from a splittext() result

Tags: python-3.x, strip

I am trying to find out what images I am missing for a given id. Lets say I have a list of 10 id's and an outcome of 3000 images but one id may have more that one image associated so I want to know what ids are lacking an image.

I have done the code however it is not working because the result from `splitext` automatically puts `'` on the result, so when I compare `12345` to `'12345'` the result is that I am missing an image for that id.

```
image_names = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(n))[0] for n in glob.glob('C:/Users/Something/*')] 
for i in range(len(image_names)):
    pivot[i]=re.split(' |_',image_names[i])
```

I do the `re.split` because the names of my images are complex, meaning, `Property 12345_Place 0_Picture 1.png` so I want to only get the `property_id` which is `12345`.

How can I strip the `'` from the result.

Comment: `img_name="Property 12345_Place 0_Picture 1.png"; re.sub(r"(Property)(\s?)(\d+)(.*)", r"\3", img_name)` should get you the ID of an image as long as the image names are structured that way.

Comment: @Abdou I implemented the code you suggest however it is not working for me. If I do it as in my original post I get this response in which my issue is the `'`

    Property: {19895, 20008, 20012, 19982}
    Images: ['19895', '19982', '20008', '20012']

When I use your code I get this:

    Property: {19895, 20008, 20012, 19982}
    Images: ['9', '9', '0', '0']

What I need is the whole id number and I think this is only getting the third digit. Also, some ids might be bigger than the ones presented here, it is not really standardized to a specific size.

Comment: @RobertoBernal I tried Abdou's regexp and it's working. However, try `re.search(r'(?<=Property )(\d+)(?=_)', img_name)[0]`, it should also return your ID.

Comment: I have solved the issue, turns out one the list of `property_id` was a list of numbers trying to compare agains a list of strings so once I set everything to strings the issue got solved.